# how to use Dynamic Imports and entry point Code Splitting in webpack 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, code-splitting

in my project i use react with webpack 4 and babel.
and i use dynamic import `import()` for loading routed component by `react-router`

#### the desiered output from weback:

- vendor.bundle.js : contains specific main vendors
  `[
    'babel-polyfill',
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    'redux',
    'redux-thunk',
    'moment',
  ]`
- main.bundle.js : entry point bundle
- bundles for each page generated from dynamic import

my current webpack configration :

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const rootPath = process.cwd();
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    vendor: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'redux',
      'redux-thunk',
      'moment',
    ],
    main: ['./client/src/index.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      // compile js
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
            plugins: ['react-hot-loader/babel'],
            babelrc: false,
          },
        },
      },
      // compile sass
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'],
      }, 
      {
        test: require.resolve('blueimp-file-upload'),
        loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false',
      },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: `${rootPath}/client/index.html`,
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './client',
    port: 6000,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
};
```

but this produce:
 *  main.bundle.js include all the vendors react ,react-dom ,etc...
 *  and vendor.bundle.js also contain vendors react ,react-dom ,etc...
 *  home.bundle.js  and the other pages plus automatic generated vendors `vendors~Article~NewArticle.bundle.js`,`vendors~Profile/index.bundle.js`

how to avoid any code duplication?

Comment: Hey I have created a [react-startkit](https://github.com/eGroupTeam/react-startkit) hope this can help you.

Comment: You don't need to modify config in webpack 4 it will automatic separate your files check the src/entry.jsx file.

Comment: You'll need syntax-dynamic-import this plugin

Comment: Also is a bad practice to add a vendors chunk as an entry point.

Comment: @MatheusSilva , why is it a bad practice? i'm spparating vendors so it can be cached and the user doesn't have to download whole bundle with every change

Comment: You should use spliChunks, it takes care of separating all your vendors file. By putting that on the entrypoint, you are saying those are part of your (your code) application. But they are not, they are dependencies of your application. SplitChunks is what CommonChunksPlugin used to be on version 3